# Acquiring an electron emitting mechanism for the double slit experiment with electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment

I want to do the double slit experiment with electrons, and for that I need an electron emitting mechanism. I've been researching this topic on the internet, and I've come across electron guns that can't be bought, and things called electron vacuums that look weird.

Can you help me get an electron emitting mechanism? For example, by providing a website link or by typing the mechanism name.

Comment: Also why do the double slit experiment since the outcome is known??

Comment: The main barrier you're going to run into, is that the entire experiment has to be done inside a vacuum. I think that's the reason you can't just buy an electron gun at the electronic parts store: it's useless without a vacuum chamber, and you might need one customized for your vacuum chamber anyway. Nonetheless there are many people who have done vacuum electron experiments on youtube and you might benefit by watching how they do it with home-made apparatus (yours will also be home-made).

Comment: @MissMulan imagine if nobody ever did their own experiments after the first time....

Comment: Yes but the double slit experinent has already be done not once, not twice but like a thousand times...

Comment: @MissMulan:  The double slit experiment has been done a bazillion times.  Most every physic course in high school does it, and nearly everybody who studies physics at a university level has done it.  There are many reasons to do it.  First off is that it is cool as heck to actually be able to see quantum weirdness with your own eyes.  After that, there's the practical part where you learn to assemble lab equipment to carry out an experiment.  The result is known, but getting the equipment to work right is not always trivial.

Comment: In this case, getting the equipment set up is a challenge.  It requires learning how to make an electron beam, which will probably involve making a vacuum tube, an accelerator, a double slit fit to pass electrons, and a detector of some type that will work in a vacuum and be able to show the interference pattern.

Comment: An electron gun and vacuum are both present in any CRT. Not sure if you can use the shadow mask as your slits, but might be worth a try.

Comment: @stark - the shadow mask is way too big to be useful for diffraction (just think what the TV picture would look like if they were sized properly for the experiment). It would be like using a laser pointer and your two windows in the living room to see an effect. In a TEM (or an SEM) to see diffraction requires atom spacings like those in a crystal.

Comment: @JRE, "Quantum weirdness?" In a high school version of the double slit? I am thinking that the only way to see "quantum weirdness" is to send one photon at a time through the apparatus. Is there a single-photon imager that a high school physics classroom can afford?

Comment: @SolomonSlow:  I don't know about you, but I find it weird enough that photons (particles) are also waves and so have interference patterns.  That's plenty of "quantum weirdness" for me.

Comment: @JRE, Yes, but you don't need photons to explain the basic double slit experiment. It can be explained classically. I demonstrated the double slit (and other wave phenomena) in a tray of water in front of my physics classroom when I was an 11th grader. No quantum anything about it. No particles. It was all just waves. It only gets weird when we show that the smallest quantity of light is a discrete quantum of energy—a photon—that seems to be point-like, and that can be counted; and then we ask, "how does a single photon know whether one slit or both slits are open?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow that may be an argument for the simulated universe theory ... lol

Answer (score 8):

The vacuum requirement can be relaxed (to require only a high instead of ultra-high vacuum) if you use higher electron energies on the order of keV. The disadvtange is that you need very small "slits" to diffract with that high energy. You want large diffraction angles because otherwise your lackluster optics will ruin the outcome. That is why atomic lattices of crystalline surfaces are good starting points for electron diffraction. Of all the electron diffraction techniques, the RHEED is probably the easiest for hobbyist use.

For RHEED, you need:

- a vacuum chamber with better than ~1e-5 mbar vacuum. Can be still sealed using o-rings.
- a turbopump and prepump
- a phosphorous screen, can be salvaged from old CRT, e.g. oscilloscope. The vacuum chamber should have a window or be all glass, so you can see the screen
- the electron gun, which is best bought as a integrated part, aim for electron energies of at least a few keV. Alternatively, also salvage from old CRT, but I am not sure if the beam quality is good enough; maybe with a small hole in a plate for collimation.
- power supply for the electron gun. could be also salvaged from a CRT
- a crystal. As surface oxide will ruin the diffraction for silicon crystals, best look for oxides. An Al2O3 crystal might be the simplest thing to obtain and will be pretty inert.

The specular reflection in RHEED will be much much brighter than the diffraction effects. So typically you aim the specular reflection away from the screen, onto a dummy plate and only capture the diffracted potion of the outgoing electrons on screen.

Comment: OP should be aware that old CRT's can be fatally dangerous to mess around with if you don't know what you are doing.